# Can I see/change user's password as an admin?

Tags: civimember

Is there any way to see or change a user's password in my organisation through admin controls?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. If you could provide some info on what CMS your instance is running on I'm sure someone in the community can help. But in brief you should be able to as long as you have administrator rights on your system.

Comment: Agree - the password is a CMS option, therefore not a CRM question. Also note that if you are using Spark pls make that clear in the question.

Comment: Also please note that you shouldn't be able to see another user's password (or indeed your own password once you've saved it). You should only be able to reset the password. Good security practice is that passwords are 'hashed' before they are stored in a database. This means that if an attacker has access to a database they are unable to (easily) decrypt the passwords. See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html